# procedures for creating the bootable usb not working for me

Tags: boot, usb, asus

Paragraphs 2-4 comprise my original elaboration on this problem. The procedures listed in the answers to the question of which many say this is a duplicate have not worked for me (as per what follows). I've now tried the rufus tool in addition to all that. So far all people are saying is that others have asked the question I ask, when in fact what I'm asking is, "Why do those answers not work for me?" Are folks reading only the title and not all the text I've typed into this box? That's what it seems like. Very frustrating. On the verge of giving up here.

Utter beginner here. I think I figured out how to boot from USB, but when I do I get error codes (device not accepting address...; unable to enumerate usb device; unable to find a medium containing a live file system). I do get a command line I can do some things with (I mean like "date" - just trying to learn this from the ground floor), but obviously there's a problem.

I see a bewildering amount of forum posts but nothing I can make sense of. All solutions are above my head ... patches of code or commands I don't understand and wouldn't know where/how to execute. I just want a functional command line I can play with so I can learn which way is up.

I have an ASUS eee PC 1015. I've now tried Ubuntu and Lubuntu with Universal USB Installer, and just a minute ago, Ubuntu with Unetbootin. Same result. Help?

Comment: Try using another USB stick. You should get to a desktop and not any command lines.

Comment: So is it usual that one USB stick doesn't work and another does? Do I indiscriminately buy a different brand or something? I can't say I'd feel great about that.

Comment: WHat did you use to prepare the USB?

Comment: I just formatted it with windows - fat32. Then I used universal usb installer from pendrivelinux.

Comment: Could be, Dylan. I've read so many. I followed the instructions from pendrivelinux and ran into the troubles I've described. Haven't found any solutions that I could understand, anyway.

Comment: It also seems unfair to saddle this question with a negative one when the suggested thread does not address the problem I'm having. I don't get it.

Comment: There's a "solved" thread on ubuntuforums for this same issue on the same machine, maybe take a look here -http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864795

Comment: In that thread, folks can't get into bios. I have no problem there. Once ubuntu / lubuntu starts, I get the error messages I've listed in the first paragraph of my question, a problem to which I've not seen any solutions I can understand.

Comment: Darn! sorry it was no good.

Comment: Thanks, though. I should've started with that. This is frustrating.

Comment: I'd like to focus my subsequent questions on whether there's an issue with your BIOS, that prevents booting USB drives. Have you ever successfully booted from a USB drive with it? Can other computers boot the USB drive you created?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try using "rufus usb tool" to create the bootable usb stick.
Rufus is a free and easy to use tool and can be downloadable from here: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

And to install or run linux from usb try the following procedure:

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-14-04-install-guide.html

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Will give it a try. Going to read all the stuff at dedoimedo beforehand. Thanks.

Comment: I am curious why you recommended `rufus` as opposed to `unetbootin` or `Linux Live USB`? What are the advantages do you feel?

Comment: I recommended to use rufus because he said he formatted the usb stick with windows-fat32. So, I thought he is a newbie and thats why i said rufus but theres nothing special than that @Dylan